# How to use timestamp in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to insert current  time and date of SO-NUMBER which user is inputting. here i am facing problem in IF..ELSE loop,
its updating only one column in the database i.e "samplerecived" column if i select "qccheck" option also.
Below is the script for html and php respectively.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="insert.php" >
<p>
<lable>ENTER SO NUMBER</lable>
<input type="text"  name="soid" id="soid" maxlength="6" required>
<p>
<lable>SELECT DEPARTMENT</lable>
<select type="text"  name="dept" id="dept">

<option value="NGS Analysis">NGS Analysis</option>
<option value="E-Array">E-Array</option>
<option value="Micro-Array">Micro-Array</option>
<option value="NGS Data">NGS Data</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<lable>SELECT STATUS</lable>
<select name="options">
<option value="Sample Recived" name="samplerecived">Sample Recived</option>
<option value="QC Check" name="qccheck">QC Check</option>

</select>
</p>
<p><button><img src="http://brandonmadeawebsite.com/images/art/icons/insert_icon.png"  height="50" />INSERT</button></p>
</form>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
 $so = $_POST['soid'];
 $dp = $_POST['dept'];
$selected = $_POST['samplerecived'];
$selected1 = $_POST['qccheck'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "status";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if($selected = 1){
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO $dbname.statusinfo (soid, dept, samplerecived) VALUES ('$so','$dp',NOW())")or die(mysqli_error($conn));

}

else{
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO $dbname.statusinfo (soid, dept,  qccheck) VALUES ('$so','$dp',NOW())")or die(mysqli_error($conn));

}
echo "Inserted sucessfully with So Number <u><b>$so</b></u> Corresponding Status is <u><b>$st</b></u>";
$conn->close();
?>
```

the output i am getting is
only "samplerecived" column is updating with current timestamp if user choose "qccheck "also.
Now i need is, if user selects "qccheck" option in the web page than in database only "qccheck" column should update with current timestamp.
if user selects "samplerecived" option in the web page than in database only "samplerecived" column should update with current timestamp.

kindly rectify the problem in script, thanks in advance guys.

Comment: `if($selected ==1){` `=`is use for assign and `==` is use for compair.

Comment: your query is really horrible and open to sql injection instead use prepared statements and save your life

Comment: @saty Thanks , Now its updating only "qccheck" column not "samplerecived" column. what to do now??

Comment: @AdityaK now you should learn to understand that *INSERT* is not the same as *UPDATE* and how if-statements work

Comment: i known sir its not update , but user will select one of the options from the dropdown options, and he will enter some number in SO-Number field and hit insert button.once he hit the button than database will get one inserted data right? based on the selected option database time stamp should inserted in column. Now u got my point sir, if u have still dought than fell free to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php script should be like this

```
<?php
 $so = $_POST['soid'];
 $dp = $_POST['dept'];
$selected = $_POST['options'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "status";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if($selected == 'Sample Recived'){
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO $dbname.statusinfo (soid, dept, samplerecived) VALUES ('$so','$dp',NOW())")or die(mysqli_error($conn));

}

else{
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO $dbname.statusinfo (soid, dept,  qccheck) VALUES ('$so','$dp',NOW())")or die(mysqli_error($conn));

}
echo "Inserted sucessfully with So Number <u><b>$so</b></u> Corresponding Status is <u><b>$st</b></u>";
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your woderful reply script, its working ,

Answer (score 1):

Is this your requirement?

```
<?php

$option = $_POST['options'];
if($option == 'Sample Recived')
  // Update timestamp of sample recieved
else
 // Update timestamp of qccheck
```

Comment: no sir, instead of "options" i have column name as "samplerecived". i didnt have any column name as "options"

Comment: Do you need to update the timestamp based on the `SELECT STATUS`?
And please dont call me sir.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience, ya exaxtly i need what u have mentioned but small change is not update but insert.

Comment: So did you get the desired output?

Comment: y u got angry on calling sir??

Comment: Because here everyone is a student.

Comment: Nice one , i agree with u r reply, thank u so much, hope u will help me in update part also !!!!